# spacy and displacy outputs different

Tags: python, spacy

My sentence is: `She had another chemotherapy protocol history with 5-FU alone before this protocol without any significant side effects.`

When I put this in displacy (https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy/), the output contains a reference to 5-FU as a noun phrase.

[image]

However, when I annotate the text and search for noun chunks, I am not shown 5-FU as a noun chunk.

`nlp = spacy.load('en')
ax = nlp(mySentence)
for w in ax.noun_chunks: print(w)`

*edit*
Additionally, when I search for the tags with the below code I am shown 5-FU as a NN. If Spacy's annotation understands this singleton word as a noun surrounded by prepositions, why shouldn't the word be picked up as a noun phrase?
*end-edit*

My spacy version: [image]

What am I doing wrong? Is there a version difference between displaCy and the version I am using? Is there a spaCy help team to address this issue?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 3):

Displacy does some pre-processing while showing the parse tree. Here is a link to the parsing service ( built on spacy ) used by displacy :
https://github.com/explosion/spacy-services/blob/master/displacy/displacy_service/parse.py#L25

```
if collapse_phrases:
    for np in list(self.doc.noun_chunks):
        np.merge(np.root.tag_, np.root.lemma_, np.root.ent_type_)
```

Spacy [merges](https://spacy.io/docs/api/span#merge) the noun chunks in the sentence instead of treating them as seperate tokens, this is why your output is different.

[image]

The other difference would be the [models](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/models#available) that you use.
You might be using the smallest en_core_web_sm whereas Spacy might be using the bigger en_core_web_md ( though it is not mentioned officially anywhere )

Comment: Thanks. The info about models is new! However, in my version of Spacy I am getting 5-FU as a NN whereas it still doesnt come up as a noun chunk. I am updating my original question.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to solve the same problem. DisplayCy and SpaCy outputs are different (both POS tags and relationships between words).

It doesn't look like the pre-processing merging is to blame as you can disable that in DisplayCy - Settings > Collapse Phrases - for me the output still doesn't match.

It's possible that you need to use en_core_web_md model (not en_core_web_sm):

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_md
```

However I haven't tested that yet.

Comment: So .. here is the result from my research so far. The en_core_web_md model is much larger and is definitely a notch more accurate than the default en_core_web_sm model. However, it is not perfect (for that matter none is, so to say). However, DisplayCy uses a very different model (at least, according to their advertisement on the top right hand corner of the displaCy webpage where you are allowed to choose a model: Model 0.101.0 (english). This model was released sometime early 2016. To use this model you have to build it from their source code (which I havent found time to do).

Comment: So basically - I found the 'md' model good enough and learned to live with it.

Answer (score 0):

Because they upgrades to V2.0
I faced the similar problem.Then i moved to V2.0
To install a model, you'll have to download it with its full name, using the --direct flag:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm-2.0.0-alpha --direct   # English
python -m spacy download xx_ent_wiki_sm-2.0.0-alpha --direct   # Multi-language NER
```

You can load a model by calling spaCy's loader. e.g. `nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')`, or import it as a module (`import en_core_web_sm`) and call its load() method, .e.g `nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()`.

Follow the Documentation at 
https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/releases/tag/v2.0.0-alpha